# Evaluating a limit where the ratio test fails $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\sqrt{n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\sqrt{n}$.

This is what happens when I try the ratio test,

$\lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{4}\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4n^3+5n+2}{4n^2+8n+4}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}=1$

There are so many factorials in this limit that I don't have the slightest guess of how to proceed with this unfortunate failure.

Comment: $$ \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} $$ has been proved in so many MSE threads that I am just going to close this question. As already remarked multiple times, the full power of Stirling's approximation is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Stirling asymptotic formula

$$
n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
$$

and substituting

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\sqrt{n}\approx \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 2n}}{(\sqrt{2\pi n})^2}\frac{(\frac{2n}{e})^{2n}}{(\frac{n}{e})^{2n}}\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}
$$